# how to use xterm to spawn a process in another terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In my bash script, I am trying to run a process in another terminal window using following:

```
xterm -e /home/mohit/a.out
```

Now I want to redirect the output using `tee` command as follows:

```
xterm -e /home/mohit/a.out 2>&1 | tee logfile
```

But I am not getting anything in `logfile`.  Any clues, why is this happening ?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like xterm spawns a new window and executes -e in that window. once that command has completed it exits.

Because it's opened up in a new shell it's stderr stdout etc are attached to that window.

If what you want is to open that window and keep it open teeing the log file you need to quote everything you want to be executed by xterm, otherwise bash will interpret the redirections and pipes itself. eg

```
xterm -e /home/mohit/a.out 2>&1 | tee logfile
```

will be translated by bash into:

use xterm to execute the command /home/mohit/a.out
then redirect stderr to stdout and pipe into tee.

As xterm spawns new window with new stdout etc. the tee doesn't get any input an therefore nothing in logfile

Try

```
xterm -e '/home/mohit/a.out 2>&1 | tee logfile'
```

which will force xterm to execute the whole pipeling

Answer (score 1):

@peteches already showed, how to capture the output by giving the whole command line to `-e`.

You can also ask [`xterm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm) to capture all output to a logfile with `-l`

```
xterm -l -e /home/mohit/a.out
```

which logs to a file called `XtermLog.XXXXXX` or `Xterm.log.hostname.yyyy.mm.dd.hh.mm.ss.XXXXXX`

You can specify the logfile with `-lf`

```
xterm -l -lf logfile -e /home/mohit/a.out
```

The drawback is, this doesn't work with existing files. You must remove `logfile`, before xterm will use it.